# How does elasticsearch snapshot/restore work

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.4.4 and need to use the snapshot/restore mechanism to backup data. But I have a few questions about it.

```
1. Can a snapshot be taken without any issues while data is being written into ES. 
2. Does it matter which of master/data/client node is being used for taking snapshots. 
3.Does restore require indices to be closed.If yes then why
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Does not. Most **important** that **storage** where you want to write data **is available** to access **from all cluster nodes**. Because data are replicated via your cluster and I think you dont have control who will backup your data
3. No you can snapshot open indicies
   [Read a bit more](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-snapshot-and-restore) about [it and here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/backing-up-your-cluster.html)